# What is a ladder-like practice tool called in Japanese?

Tags: word-choice, sports

I often find a ladder-like practice tool as shown in the following figure in many dojos or sport halls in Japan.

[image: 肋木 wall bars]

What is it called? As a bonus, what is it for?

Comment: Sorry, but I find your "bonus" question a little bit weird. These "things" can be found in virtually every school in my country and virtually every kid knows... what is it for. Is this some kind of joke that I don't get? :>

Comment: @Kik Good... because I don't like jokes that I don't understand! :> But, seriously... well... then this is my mistake (sorry!). Where I live (Poland) this is one of the mostly remembered thing from school and certainly one of the most recognizable element of school's gymnastics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe these are 肋木 *rokuboku* "wall bars".

As to what they are for... to climb up and down. More info on [Japanese](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%82%8B%E6%9C%A8) or [English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_bars).